# SQL query fails to insert with same column count, works with fewer columns inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

In the example here, NULL values are normally other variables I pass through. I tried to pass NULL to see if that was the problem as those are the only values that can be NULL, everything else is required.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `imstillr_crm`.`customerinfo` 
            (`id`, `companyname`, `primarycontact`, `primaryemail`, 
             `prefphone`, `secondarycontact`, `secondaryemail`, `optionalphone`, 
             `department`, `website`) 
           VALUES 
             (NULL, '".$company."', '".$primarycontact."', '".$primaryemail."', 
              '".$prefphone."', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL, 
              '".$department."', '".$website."')");
```

I just tried this with fewer variables and it worked. I'm kinda confused. I even inserted a record and copied the SQL string and added my variables.

Answer (score 6):

I think you've made a mistake here:

```
'NULL, '".$department.
```

Presumably you intended

```
'NULL', ".$department."
```

BUT: this looks as though you are attempting to insert the literal text "NULL" into your database which I assume is not what you intend. NULL is a keyword so you can just use the bare word NULL wherever you are inserting a null value (so no quotes required around it).

There's more though, at the risk of distracting you from your current issue, you really should not execute SQL statements by composing a string as you are doing. This is how SQL injection attacks succeed. A better way is to use PDO with prepared statements. Here's a quick description of how to use it:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

The main advantages are:

1. You remove the explicit dependency on Mysql created by the mysql_* functions
2. You can avoid SQL injection attacks.
3. Your code should be easier to read without the complex string composition

Just for completeness, here's how your code would look with PDO

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO imstillr_crm.customerinfo (id, companyname, primarycontact, primaryemail, prefphone, secondarycontact, secondaryemail, optionalphone, department, website) VALUES (:id, :companyname, :primarycontact, :primaryemail, :prefphone, :secondarycontact, :secondaryemail, :optionalphone, :department, :website)");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", NULL);
$stmt->bindParam(":companyname", $company);
$stmt->bindParam(":primarycontact", $primarycontact);

...

$stmt->execute();
```

Notice how you don't need to put quotes around the values. They might contain various characters so as quotes, semi colons etc. and these won't cause any problems in your database (they may cause problems elsewhere in your app but that's another discussion).

Comment: i was putting it in a single quote then double quote so i could insert the variable like so is that not correct?

'".$preferphone."'

Comment: Yes, where you're actually putting in a non null value, that will work but if you're putting in a null, you don't want the quotes around it. The point about the PDO thing is that what you are doing above is dangerous. If the user enters a single quote in one of their fields, you will generate an SQL error. If they are smart, they can exploit this to force execution of arbitrary SQL statements. You can try prevent this by removing suspicious characters such as quotes and semi colons but you'll be fighting a losing battle, better to let the library writers take care of this (hence PDO).

Comment: FYI, I've updated the example above to show how your code would look if you were to use PDO. Note also that the same lesson applies equally to other programming environments (.Net, Java, Perl etc.).

Comment: yeah with .net i use stored procedures ill have to check PDO out though

Comment: got it working my original way and wouldnt mysql_real_escape_string on my posts protect from sql injection? I also added record and with company name Bedo's and it sent fine. What could be something i could test for an sql injection

Comment: If you're going to continue to use the mysql_* functions then certainly, apply the mysql_real_escape_string to your inputs. The problem with this approach is that it's error prone, you might apply a quick fix to your app at some point in the future and forget to escape the input. There's a good resource on SQL injection in general here: http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/ it had a few things that I hadn't thought of myself. To test, just try inserting some of the examples that you see on the linked page, if they get inserted without any errors, you're probably ok.

Comment: One final thing, it's a good idea to filter all of your request values with a regular expression before you use them. For example, if you're expecting an int value, you might use something like: $filteredValue = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $inputValue);

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can put `NULL` in quotes. I think you need to remove the quotes around NULL otherwise MySQL (I'm guessing MySQL) will treat them as strings.

Comment: Unless, of course, if he's literally adding the string 'NULL'. For some reason.

Comment: I think it'd be save to assume josh isn't trying to add string null to a field...but then again...

Answer (score 1):

A `'` is missing after the last NULL
Corrected code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `imstillr_crm`.`customerinfo` (`id`, `companyname`, `primarycontact`, `primaryemail`, `prefphone`, `secondarycontact`, `secondaryemail`, `optionalphone`, `department`, `website`) VALUES (NULL, '".$company."', '".$primarycontact."', '".$primaryemail."', '".$prefphone."', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '".$department."', '".$website."')");
```

Comment: yeah noticed that just now, but null shouldn't be in quotes anyway so it was a double no

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the `'` and `,`:

```
'NULL, '".$department."'
```

Should be:

```
'NULL', '".$department."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right before $department you have 'NULL, '"  you probably want to move the quote in before the comma.